# What could go wrong if you don't pass objects by reference into a function

Tags: c++, reference

I am trying to teach some students that in the following case you should pass by reference, otherwise the objects will be copied.

note: They don't know about copy-constructors yet, so if possible I would not like to mention them in the example.

```
int sumOfSizes(CObject const & a, CObject const & b)
{
    return a.getSize() + b.getSize();
}
```

Can anybody help me with a real-world example where the sum is infact not what is expected?

Comment: Such an example would probably indicate bad design for `CObject`.

Comment: Both parameters should be CObject const &

Comment: The main argument would be performance, not correctness, wouldn't it? Suppose each CObject contains a million strings - copying just to determine size would be a bad idea.

Comment: seeing as how copy constructors are central to the problem I would start off by using a primitive type example and comparing it to a complex object. The primitive example would introduce them to the idea of pass-by-value using a copy, and then move onto why a copy might be a bad idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Space_C0wb0y implied in his comment, the only way this could do something "unexpected" when passing by value is if the copy constructor for `CObject` did something "unexpected" (such that the local `CObject` instances were not equivalent (in whatever sense) to the original instances).  This in turn would indicate bad design.

Therefore, your counterexample will have to rely on a contrived, badly-designed `CObject`.